# Should I upvote answers if I'm not sure they're correct?

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes

Say they're answers to my own question, so I can't confirm or deny that the answers are correct. Should I upvote them anyway?

Comment: Why would you not be able to confirm or deny that the answers to your own questions are correct?  You should be in a position to test whatever answers you get.

Comment: Why would you even consider voting for a answer without reasonable certainty that it was right?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to confirm or deny that the answers to your own questions are correct. But if you are really not sure then don't vote (neither upvote nor downvote). Instead, comment to those answers and ask them to describe their answers in details.

Answer (score 7):

If you mouseover the upvote arrows on the answers, there's a tooltip that says:

> This answer is useful (click again to undo)

It doesn't say: "This answer is 100%, verifiably correct and the best answer."

If there's information in the answer that helps you, it may be worth upvoting. However, it's up to you what you do with your votes, despite what the tooltips say, as long as you're voting on the content and not the people. :)

Answer (score 4):

There is no time limit in voting. Don't let others pressure you. Take your time to confirm the answers you get. And if helpful upvote them.